# Adding Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.3 to Ember application

Tags: css, json, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm trying to update my Bootstrap dependency in my Ember application to the alpha 4 version so I can access the utility classes (such as margin/padding).

I think Bootstrap is a bower dependency since it's listed in `bower.json`, so I followed the instructions from [the new Bootstrap website](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/):

`bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.3`

When I did this, `bower.json` didn't update. In fact, Bootstrap version is still `"bootstrap": "^3.3.7"`.

The only differences are:

1. Now I have 152 JSHint errors in my terminal...I tried adding `"bootstrap":true` to `.jshintrc` and restarted my server but the errors were still there.
2. My ember app was broken until I removed line 1 in `change-version.js`, which was `#!/usr/bin/env node`.
3. When I start typing a new css style in my templates, the CSS styles are showing up, but my Ember application is not recognizing them. For example, here is an image: [image: shows up but doesn't actually work]

When I add the class `m-r-3` and reload localhost, nothing shows up.

I've already tried importing `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.css` in the `ember-cli-build.js` file. It didn't work.

I have already read through [this page which goes over dependencies](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/) but I have had no luck. If anyone could assist here that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `--save` parameter to save bower.json:

```
bower install --save bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.3
```

Look at the bower_components directory, does it keep the old version of the bootstrap? If so remove it.

You should add `bootstrap.css` to the `ember-cli-build.js`, as you said. Have a look at [this addon](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/index.js), check your coding against of a typo or erronous adding.

Does your client loads any version of bootstrap? (Check vendor.js)

Comment: Okay, just did that. Will I also have to npm install the newest version of bootstrap?

Also yes, my client did load bootstrap, but it is the 3.3.7 version.

Comment: Does your `package.json` contains anything about bootstrap? If so you need to delete the dependency line.  You should find where the old version is coming from. To be sure, clean *bower_components, node_modules, tmp and dist* directories. After that run `npm install` and `bower install`.